# Invariant dimension property and a ring epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, invariance, dimension-theory-algebra, epimorphisms

In Hungerford's *Algebra*, p. 186, the Proposition 2.11 says

Let $f:R\to S$ be a nonzero epimorphism of rings with identity. If $S$ has the invariant dimension property (IDP), then so does $R$.

It is true, and the proof is logical. However, my problem is about the converse;

> if $R$ has the IDP, then does $S$ have the IDP too?

We do not need to handle infinite basis cases or commutative ring cases, because that is true... (Theorem 2.6 Corollary 2.12).

Comment: IDP is known as [IBN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number) (invariant basis number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be any ring without IBN, and let $T$ be any ring with IBN.

There is a projection $S\times T \to T$, so $S\times T$ has $IBN$.  But then the projection $S\times T \to S$ is a counterexample.

Comment: GOOD! But The projection should map onto S.

Comment: The reason SxT has IBN. USE the matrix version definition of IBN at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number

Comment: The proof about the relation between original definition and matrix definition is that isomorphisms can have finite matrix form when considering only finite bases of $R^n, R^m$

Comment: @miku I am considering both projections.  If $R=S\times T$, then the existence of an epimorphism $R\to T$ implies that $R$ has IBN, by the Hungerford proposition you quoted.  _Then_ I am taking the projection $R\to S$ as a counterexample.

Comment: Such a good and useful proof!